# THREE.js improve performance on Drag select

Tags: performance, three.js, selection

I have to create millions of vectors based on the coordinates. I am using THree.js LineSegments for the same and it is pretty good performance wise. But to implement selection of area on drag the fps drops to 0. It is because I am creating those many individual LineSegments to be added to Object3D(helperObj) which can be used by SelectionBox. Although I am not adding the Object3D(helperObj) to scene still because of so many draw calls inside the loop it is causing the performance issue. For showing the lines I am using BufferGeometry and pushing the coordinates inside loop and adding them at once after the loop is over(lineGeometry in the working example).

```
/** code causing performance issue starts**/
   const geo = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
   geo.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([x1, y1, 0, x2, y2, 0], 3));
   const helperLine = new THREE.LineSegments(geo, hoveredMaterial);
   helperLine.visible = false;
   helperLine.userData = "row:"+i;
   helperObj.add(helperLine);
/** code causing performance issue ends**/
```

I need some data that I am adding in userData of helperObj for doing some operations. Is there any other way I can add userData without creating multiple LineSegments.

Working example : https://codepen.io/raksha-jain/pen/JjWPVbK

Can someone please help?

Comment: I recommend you create *a single* `LineSegments` object with hundreds of lines, and then change how many lines you're actually rendering with `mesh.geometry.setDrawRange(0, max);`. Take a look at the code [in this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_drawrange) for a demo. You can dynamically update the start & end positions of each vertex, then show/hide some of them with `setDrawRange()`. This is way more efficient than building a new `LineSegment` for each line.

Comment: I have no issues in drawing those hundreds of lines. It is done using lineGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(positions, 3)); and is quite fast. But on box selection I need those individual lines data as done in here: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=selection#misc_boxselection . It works fine in the example as it has only 200 cubes. I need the line data for each line in the boxselection to perform some operations in my app. Is there any other way to achieve box selection and get individual line data?

Comment: I suggest creating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from your ID to a specific index in a single _indexed_ `LineSegments` geometry. You can then use your ID to access that index, from which you can perform many operations. Reducing your data and adding the map is non-trivial (which is why I'm not making this a full-fledged answer...), but the result will be faster access to specific parts of your geometry via your ID.

Comment: Can you give an example of how can create indexed LineSegments. I did not understand from the standard example given by Three.js